# add a glyphicon-user to a TextBoxFor control in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, razor, glyphicons

I want to show a glyphicon-user at the end of a textBoxFor control in MVC C# but I can't accomplished yet, in the code I show (razor commented @* *@) the span tags that I tried in order to get the glyphicon but didn't work out, could you please help me

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.usuario, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })  
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>*@

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.usuario, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Usuario", @type = "text" })
                    @*<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>*@
                    <p class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.usuario)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue?  Is the glyphicon appearing under the text area?

Comment: exactly, if I use the code in the span tags it shows the glyphicon image but it uses the same space that  the textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.  You just forgot to include a `div` element with the class name `input-group`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.usuario, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">  
        <div class="input-group"> // missing div 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.usuario, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Usuario" })
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <p class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.usuario)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you don't need this in your `TextBoxFor`.. `@type = "text"`

Here is [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OqkEGjGGHa).

Hopefully this helps.